# Change caption of Figure

Tags: captions

Caption of the following figure is coming `Figure 1: abc`

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=12cm]{Fig.jpg}
\caption{abcd}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
```

I want to change caption as `Figure S1: abc`

Comment: What packages are you loading, what is your document class? More information is required to be able to answer this, please extend your code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completed your code to an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) (please always do that yourself). Your goal can be achieved by the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
   \let\oldthefigure\thefigure % Store old \thefigure-command.
   \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\oldthefigure}  % Create new \thefigure-command by prepending an "S".
   \begin{figure}[!h]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=12cm]{example-image-duck}
      \caption{abcd}
      \label{fig}
   \end{figure}
   See Figure~\ref{fig}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you load the [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package, you can make adjustments to captions with `\captionsetup`. How you want the changes depends on where you put this macro. If you want all captions in figures to be changed, add the lines in your preamble

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{<<the name>>}{#1 S#2}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=<<the name>>}
```

However, if you want only a selected figure to be affected, keep `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` in the preamble and add the other command in the `figure` environment without optional argument

```
\captionsetup{labelformat=<<the name>>}
```

The full code with global settings:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{labelwiths}{#1 S#2}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=labelwiths}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=12cm]{Fig.jpg}
  \caption{abcd}
  \label{fig}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=12cm]{Fig.jpg}
  \caption{Sample sample sample}
  \label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]